# Dockerised NuxtJS app do not reload local changes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nuxt.js

I just Dockerised my first NuxtJS app using Docker and Docker-compose.
All run smoothly except that when I make a change on my local, the running docker does not reflect the changes I've made.

How do I configure the Docker container to listen to local changes in my code? Thanks:

**Dockerfile:**

```
# Dockerfile
FROM node:11.13.0-alpine

# create destination directory
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp

# Add current directory code to working directory
ADD . /myapp/

# update and install dependency
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add git

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV NUXT_PORT=3000

CMD gunicorn myapp.wsgi:application --bind $NUXT_HOST:$NUXT_PORT
```

**Docker-compose:**

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  nuxt:
    build: .
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - NUXT_PORT=3000
    volumes:
      - /myapp/
```

**Nuxt.config.js:**

```js
export default {
  // Global page headers (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head)
  head: {
    title: 'myapp',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }],
  },

  // Global CSS (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css)
  css: [],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins)
  plugins: [],

  // Auto import components (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components)
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended) (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules)
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/eslint
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/stylelint
    '@nuxtjs/stylelint-module',
  ],

  // Modules (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules)
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/buefy
    'nuxt-buefy',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/pwa
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/content
    '@nuxt/content',
  ],

  // Axios module configuration (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios)
  axios: {},

  // Content module configuration (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-content)
  content: {},

  // Build Configuration (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build)
  build: {},

  watchers: {
    webpack: {
      poll: true
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: What are you getting from Docker here; why not use your host's Node installation and `npm run dev` there?

Comment: (That particular `volumes:` syntax creates an _anonymous volume_ for your application content: you are running neither your host's content nor what's in the image, but rather some old build of the application.  I'd recommend deleting it to use the code built into the image.  You need different syntax like `.:/myapp` to replace the image content with the host content.)

Comment: Thanks David, this solved my issue. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

add this to nuxt.config.ts

specify your containers host

```
//fix issue for docker not reflecting changes
  vite: {
    server: {
      host: true,
      port: 3000,
      watch: {
        usePolling: true,
      },
    },
  }
```

alternative:

```
 //fix issue for docker not reflecting changes
  vite: {
    server: {
      watch: {
        usePolling: true,
        interval: 100, // Poll files every 100ms
      },
    }
  }
```